# i fail to get my css file to link it with the index file

Tags: html, css, relative-url

Root file is Practise2 folder:

```
-Resources (folder)
-php_script (folder)
-index.php (file)
```

inside Resources file:

```
-html (folder)
-styles (folder)
-images (folder)
```

inside the styles folder:

```
-login.css (file)
```

I want to link the login.css file with the index.php file

index.php linking code…

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Resources/styles/login.css">
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your directory so its easier to understand?

Comment: Also add the code that actually includes the css file. Which folder is the web servers document root?

Comment: Try `href="styles/login.css"` then it's relative to the PHP file

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dot to the previous Resources folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Resources/styles/login.css">
```